# Google Cloud Logs Router not exporting every hour

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've set up a Google Cloud Logs Router ([Exporting with the Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2)) to export our app engine logs to a Google Storage bucket. Normally every hour a new .json file with the logs of the past hour should be created on the bucket. The first few hours it worked as expected, however after a while some hours were skipped (even though there were logs for these hours) and after a day, no new exports were made at all.

Is this a bug in the Logs Export functionality or might it be due to settings?

Comment: Settings. Unless you see an alert on GCP [Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) about "Operations" having a disruption this behavior it is always related to wrong configurations on your side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any idea which settings might be causing this? I'm unable to find any possible setting that causes not exporting every hour.

Comment: On [Exporting with the Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#troubleshooting) page you may find a troubleshooting steps to determine the reason for this bevavior. Try to follow the steps and add that information to the question. The most common one is this: `No matching log entries have been received since you created or updated your sink; only new log entries are exported.`